# What is the difference between staging and caching?

Tags: git

I'm reading the book [Pro Git, second edition](https://progit.org/).

It says, on page 21:

> `git diff --staged` This command compares your staged changes to your last commit.

and a page later (without explaining what cached means)

> `git diff --cached` to see what you've staged so far.

and now I'm a bit lost. What is the difference between staging and caching?

Comment: They're exact synonyms. `--cached` is older than `--staged`; the latter was added for consistency with the term "staging area".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “staging area”, or “cache” are both synonyms for the same thing which has another name in most other contexts in Git: **The index**.

The index is the area where changes are *staged* when you add them using `git add` (or `git rm`). It’s the set of changes that is committed when you do `git commit`.

All three names are usually used synonymously, although “cache” is rarely used outside of the `--cached` parameter in `git diff`.

Comment: The `--cached` parameter also exists for `git rm`, `git diff-index`, and perhaps others. The more user-friendly `--staged` synonym isn't available everywhere just yet, which may add to the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

They are synonymous; from the [Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named . Typically you would want comparison with the latest commit, so if you do not give , it defaults to HEAD. If HEAD does not exist (e.g. unborn branches) and  is not given, it shows all staged changes. --staged is a synonym of --cached.